# Early vs. early on

Tags: difference

What is difference between those to phrases. For example:

> I decided to get rid of the car early on before Mike crashed in to a
>   pole.

What is "on" there for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**early *on*** refers to a time not long after the beginning.

**on** conveys the idea of some time transpiring / having transpired.

If something is apparent from the very first moment, we'd say

> It was clear from the start that ...
>
> It was clear from the very beginning that ...
>
> It was clear from the get-go that...

When it takes a little time, we'd say

> Things started out fine, but early on it became clear that ...